# How can I rebase local branch into origin without merging?

Tags: git, rebasing

I have the following case

```
o--A--B--C <-origin/master
 \-D--E <-master
```

I would like to achieve the following

```
o--A--B--C--D--E <-origin/master
```

and also keeping the tags at `D` and `E`.

If I do a rebase then the `D` and `E` would be merged resulting `D'` and `E'`

```
o--A--B--C--D'--E' <-origin/master
```

<s>Also the tags would not be moved and still pointing to hash of commit `D` and `E`.</s>

**Update 1**

If I have file `A.txt` at `C` and file `B.txt` at `D`, the rebase will keep both `A.txt` and `B.txt` at commit `D'`. How can I do a rebase but preserve all the file structure and content what I had at `D`.?

Comment: D and E will always stay there, nothing can change that. Rebasing and then manually moving the tags might be the best option. Also rebasing won't merge anything... what makes you think it will?

Comment: Question title is wrong. As per the post's description you want to rebase local master to origin's master, but title says the opposite.

Comment: During rebase there are conflict and also will result to new hash.

Comment: @OHLÁLÁ every command in git which modifies the history will create a new hash. This cannot be prevented

Comment: To clarify "Update 1", when you say "I have file", do you mean A.txt is a new file that is added in commit C? And is B.txt a new file that is added in commit D?

Comment: A.txt could have been added at Commit A,B,C, and B.txt.is added at D. But A.txt does.not exist at C.

Comment: @OHLÁLÁ I assume you meant "But A.txt does not exist at **D**". So when you rebase D onto C to create D', A.txt will remain there because someone added it. If you don't want it anymore, then delete it and commit the delete. (You could amend D' to be D'' with the delete, or add another commit with the delete in it.

Answer (score 0):

If nodes D and E have tags, they will not be moved with the rebase.  D and E are placeholder names for hashes, and are not git tags.

I think you may have been using the word *tag* incorrectly, or in a casual sense.  But a `git tag` is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First lets agree on what *merge* means. You wrote:

> If I do a rebase then the D and E would be merged resulting D' and E'...

Instead of the word *merged* there, it makes more sense to say *replayed*. An actual merge in your case results in a new commit with two parents (from each branch).

There is no way to rebase *and* keep D and E commit IDs intact.

You must choose either rebase or merge. If you rebase, your commit IDs will change, and then you can make new tags for D' and E' (and perhaps discard your previous tags for D and E).

If you merge, the commit IDs for D and E will remain intact and you can use your existing tags, but you will have a merge commit and your history will not be in a straight line.

Comment: (won't D and E will remain intact as long as they're reachable?)

Comment: @evolutionxbox are you talking about them sitting off to the side and not having them in origin/master? I doubt that would be very useful. ;)